# How to edit the same file in multiple tabs in vim?

Tags: vim, tabs

I often edit long files in vim that have blocks of code in multiple disparate places in the file that I need to be constantly going back and forth between. Obviously, one way of solving this is to split the window with :split and edit each portion in a different split window, and a `:w` in either window will save the whole file. This is well and good if you have a large enough screen but sometimes I have to use vim on a low-resolution laptop and I don't want to reduce my screen space further by splitting the window.

In this case, what I'd really like to do is edit the file in multiple *tabs*, and treat each separate tab exactly like a separate view split. I can sort of mimic this by using `:tabopen <the same filename>` once I have one copy of the file open, but this is sort of hacky — it doesn't work if I've already made changes to the file because vim thinks I'm just opening the file a second time.

Is there a good way to get the behavior I want with tabs in vim?

Comment: Another way of accomplishing this is to mark places in the file with `ma`, `mb`, etc and return to the places with `'a`, `'b`, etc.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The `:tab` command takes a command as argument.

So you can do this:

```
:tab split
```

This will work even if the buffer is modified, and a save in either tab saves the file, updating the saved state in both.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `:tab` command:

> ```
> :[count]tab {cmd}`
> ```
>
> > Execute `{cmd}` and when it opens a new window open a new tab page instead. [...] When `[count]` is omitted the tab page appears after the current one. When `[count]` is specified the new tab page comes after tab page `[count]`. Use `:0tab cmd` to get the new tab page as the first one.
> >
> > Examples:
> >
> > ```
> > :tab split           " opens the current buffer in new tab page
> > :tab help gt         " opens tab page with help for "gt"
> > ```